# How do you reference nested JSON data directly?

Tags: python

I'm calling up a lot of data through an API, and it's nested within many layers. I want to be able to reference pieces easily, with bracket notation ideally.

Right now, I'm pulling the data and it comes out like this:

```
   {
    'status': 'success', 
    'data': 
          {
           'available_balance': '0.1515', 
           'pending_withdrawals': '0.0000', 
           'withdrawable_balance': '0.1515', 
           'couponable_balance': '0.0000'
          }
    }
```

I can do `balance["data"]` which then outputs:

```
   {
    'available_balance': '0.1515', 
    'pending_withdrawals': '0.0000', 
    'withdrawable_balance': '0.1515', 
    'couponable_balance': '0.0000'
   }
```

But what I want is to do something like `balance["data"["available_balance"]]` and get:

`0.1515`

Comment: Have you tried `balance["data"]["available_balance"]` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
balance['data']['available_balance']
```

JSON is loaded as nested dictionaries in python.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but if I were to have two different labels both named 'available_balance', how would I tell the program which to pick?

Comment: Well, there wouldn't be two 'available_balance' in the same scope, that doesn' t make much sense. Generally, we'd iterate over indexes in 'data' so we'd do something like: 

`balance['data'][0]['available_balance']` ,


`balance['data'][1]['available_balance']`,


`balance['data'][2]['available_balance']`,   etc